# unable to connect to https site with R

Tags: r, https

I am trying to connect to remote site via https and download some information. I am doing this:

```
library("httr")
library("XML")
library(RCurl)
url<-c("https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=3")
file<-getURL(url, ssl.verifyhost = 0L, ssl.verifypeer = 0L)
```

each row has "Details" link that gives more information on each record. I need to download the url and go into each "Details" section and merge it with the initial data set.

How can I do this?

Comment: Works for me if I leave out the second and third arguments.

Comment: If your question has changed you need change the title and the body of your question. Read [edit] and stop using comments to clarify questions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? At the very least, what have you done to get data out of this table?

Comment: @camille, I can only do what I have posted. Not too familiar with R language

Comment: That's fine. It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do, but I think whatever it is, it's too broad for an SO question. You're really looking for a full tutorial on web scraping or crawling. Also, not sure what the "initial data set" is here.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `rvest` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question you'd like to retrieve the data from the main table at the `https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=3` url, as well as the details data for each of the records in the main url.

As an example I wrote a code that lets you retrieve the data from the main page in a structured dataframe, in which the first column is the url of the details record.

```
#load libraries
library(rvest)
library (tidyverse)

#assign url
url <- "https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=3"

#extract td tags contents
readUrlHtml <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("td")

#create empty dataframe
df <- data.frame(Details=character(),
                 Sheriff=character(), 
                 SalesDate=character(),
                 Plaintiff=character(),
                 Defendant=character(),
                 Address=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#loop to harvest the data
j = 1

for (i in 1:(length(readUrlHtml)/6))
  {
    df[i,c('Details')] <- paste0("https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=",substr(readUrlHtml[j],65,73))
    df[i,c('Sheriff')] <- readUrlHtml[j+1] %>% html_text()
    df[i,c('SalesDate')] <- readUrlHtml[j+2] %>% html_text()
    df[i,c('Plaintiff')] <- readUrlHtml[j+3] %>% html_text()
    df[i,c('Defendant')] <- readUrlHtml[j+4] %>% html_text()
    df[i,c('Address')] <- readUrlHtml[j+5] %>% html_text()

    j = j + 6
  }

#values check
df[1,]

df[50,]

df[525,]
```

With the `rvest` package you'll be able to retrieve and save in a new dataframe the data of the details page.

#### EDIT 2019-03-29

In order to retrieve the details data you need to save the cookies information from the main url. Once done you can create a new dataframe to store that data: this is shown in the updated version of the code.

1) the new library `httr` is used to retrieve the cookies data

2) the details data being retrieved is the one inside the red rectangle in the printscreen (to retrieve the last I suggest to create a new dataframe to store the additional data, but I guess that this will highly increase the amount of type needed to process all the data!)

3) the two dataframes `df` & `dfDetails` may be merged by using the `Details` key

```
#load libraries
library(rvest)
library (tidyverse)
library (httr) #new library

#assign url
url <- "https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=3"

#extract td tags contents
readUrlHtml <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("td")

#create empty dataframe
df <- data.frame(Details=character(),
                 Sheriff=character(),
                 SalesDate=character(),
                 Plaintiff=character(),
                 Defendant=character(),
                 Address=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#loop to harvest the data
j = 1

for (i in 1:(length(readUrlHtml)/6))
  {
    df[i,c('Details')] <- paste0("https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=",substr(readUrlHtml[j],65,73))
    df[i,c('Sheriff')] <- readUrlHtml[j+1] %>% html_text()
    df[i,c('SalesDate')] <- readUrlHtml[j+2] %>% html_text()
    df[i,c('Plaintiff')] <- readUrlHtml[j+3] %>% html_text()
    df[i,c('Defendant')] <- readUrlHtml[j+4] %>% html_text()
    df[i,c('Address')] <- readUrlHtml[j+5] %>% html_text()

    j = j + 6
  }


#values check
df[1,]

df[50,]

df[525,]


## UPDATED SECTION TO RETRIEVE THE URLS DETAILS ##

#retrieve session cookie by taking the url of the main page
urlInfos <- GET(url)

#create empty details dataframe
dfDetails <- data.frame(Details=character(),
                 Sheriff=character(), 
                 CourtCase=character(),
                 SalesDate=character(),
                 Plaintiff=character(),
                 Defendant=character(),
                 Address=character(),
                 Description=character(),
                 ApproxUpset=character(),
                 Attorney=character(),
                 AttorneyPhone=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#loop to harvest the details
for (i in 1:length(df$Details)) #takes a while to retrieve all records! (5-6 mins)
#for (i in 1:3) #loop through few record for testing purposes
{

  responseDetail <- GET(df[i,c('Details')], set_cookies(`urlInfos$cookies[6]` = paste0('"',urlInfos$cookies[7],'"')))
  readUrlHtmlDetail <- read_html(responseDetail) %>% html_nodes("td")

  dfDetails[i,c('Details')] <- df[i,c('Details')]
  dfDetails[i,c('Sheriff')] <- readUrlHtmlDetail[2] %>% html_text()
  dfDetails[i,c('CourtCase')] <- readUrlHtmlDetail[4] %>% html_text()
  dfDetails[i,c('SalesDate')] <- readUrlHtmlDetail[6] %>% html_text()
  dfDetails[i,c('Plaintiff')] <- readUrlHtmlDetail[8] %>% html_text()
  dfDetails[i,c('Defendant')] <- readUrlHtmlDetail[10] %>% html_text()
  dfDetails[i,c('Address')] <- readUrlHtmlDetail[12] %>% html_text()
  dfDetails[i,c('ApproxUpset')] <- readUrlHtmlDetail[14] %>% html_text()
  dfDetails[i,c('Attorney')] <- readUrlHtmlDetail[16] %>% html_text()
  dfDetails[i,c('AttorneyPhone')] <- readUrlHtmlDetail[18] %>% html_text()

}


#values detail check
dfDetails[1,]

dfDetails[50,]

dfDetails[525,]
```

[image]

Comment: with this code, I can retrieve the data from the url. How about pulling data from the details link and merging the data?